# Is there any way to make Eclipse's handling of projects and workspaces work like Visual Studio?

Tags: eclipse

In other words, one folder, one project. Copy the folder, you've copied the whole project. One project open in the IDE at a time. Self-contained. Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects are organized as decribed in Eclipse. The folder where the project is stored contains all of the significant data.
However you have the considerably more powerful paradigm of workspace. A workspace is a set of preferences and projects somehow related. If you want to work with a project you copied (as in "copy the folder") you have to import it in a workspace, but that's it: it's still a single comprehensive folder.

On the other hand if you want to have one single project open in the IDE at once you have different choices:

1. use a different workspace for every project
2. close other projects (right click, "close all unrelated projects") and setup a filter to hide closed projects
3. use working sets with a single project

This way you are giving up some really cool features, though, such as importing projects into other projects.

Comment: I concur. Can we change the question to "Is there any way to make Visual Studio’s handling of projects and workspaces work like Eclipse?" ;)

Comment: I would gladly give up those features to be able to copy a folder, double click a file and be working on that project. Using a different workspace is a pain because settings are not shared. Hiding projects is not the same as not having them there in the first place. Having 100 projects open is a pain whether they're open or closed. Working sets are the best solution I've found so far, but they're still a lot more work then double-clicking a file. I work on dozens of small, independent projects. Visual Studio is brilliant for this. Eclipse not so much.